# SQL multi-command atomicity question

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create a program that updates 2 different tables using sql commands. The only thing I am worried about is that if the program updates one of the tables and then loses connection or whatever and does NOT update the other table there could be an issue. Is there a way I could either

A. Update them at the exact same time

or

B. Revert the first update if the second one fails.

Comment: I think you're looking for information on "Transactions".  Look for info on using transactions in your specific database (which you haven't specified in the tags)

Comment: what is the issue error/exception message ?

Comment: If you use a transaction, it with either do both or neither. It won't need to roll back the first update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes use a SQL transaction.  Here is the tutorial:[JDBC Transactions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the database, I'd suggest using a stored procedure or function based on the operations involved.  They're supported by:

- MySQL
- Oracle
- SQL Server
- PostgreSQL

These encapsulate a database transaction (atomic in nature -- it either happens, or it doesn't at all), without the extra weight of sending the queries over the line to the database... Because they already exist on the database, the queries are parameterized (safe from SQL injection attacks) which means less data is sent -- only the parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

Most SQL servers support transactions, that is, queueing up a set of actions and then having them happen atomically. To do this, you wrap your queries as such:

```
START TRANSACTION;
 *do stuff*
COMMIT;
```

You can consult your server's documentation for more information about what additional features it supports.  For example, [here is a more detailed discussion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) of transactions in MySQL.